# Extrude curve into 'shell', evenly thicken shell

Tags: mesh, extrude

I am entirely new to blender. I am trying to create the cover of a closed book, to that end, I have made a mesh that consists of edges and vertices (it is currently only shaped properly on the left of this image, I intend to add a mirror modifier later to fix this):

[image: Mesh]

I then extruded this into a 'shell':

[image: Shell]

So far, so good.

Next, I want to solidify the faces. This goes badly:

[image: Solidified]

I think I understand the issue - each face gets solidified separately, and they therefore extrude different amounts, and along different normals. I just don't know how to fix it. I tried merging the faces into three faces (flat left, flat right, and bent centre), but that just removes all of the shaping.

EDIT:

Object mode -> CTRL-A

[image: Scale]

Comment: have you applied scale (CTRL-A and select scale) in object mode?

Comment: If I press CTRL-A, scale is checked, yes, I'm not sure if that's what you mean

Comment: In object mode, CTRL-A should bring up a popup menu.  click on Scale to set the scale.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what comes up when I do CTRL-A and click on scale

Comment: The Solidify modifier has an 'Even Thickness' checkbox just below the 'Thickness' field which might help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your topology is just too dense, especially near the folds. (That might be making duplicate verts, or other faults, harder to find, too.)  You could start more simply, and then give the mesh a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Below, all with *Solidify*. Only the outer surface is modelled:

[image]

All with *Solidify*, *Bevel* modifiers.

1. Before subdiv. 2. After Subdiv. 3. With the *Solidify* aimed at a weighted vertex-group to vary thickness.

[image]

Trying out the Solidify modes can subtly change where the surface 'kinks', without damaging the topology